# Table View Cell is Blank after unwind from Editing scene. If terminate app and open again, Table View is displayed correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I have a strange problem in latest Xcode and Swift 2.1 .
I have a table view containing photo.
Its cell can be tapped to edit it.
After editing it, such as changing photo or text,  and unwind to tableview. The cell is blank.

It I terminate app and open app again. The Table View is displayed correctly. I can see the new photo and new text in the edited cell. So it means there is no problem in saving.

i use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths to refresh the edited cell. below is my code.

```
    @IBAction func unwindToTableView(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? BexMaintain, bex = sourceViewController.bex {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                bexs[selectedIndexPath.row] = bex
                tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
    }}}
```

and here is cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
        let bex = bexs[indexPath.row]      
        cell.name.text = bex.name       
        //fetch thumbnail
        let thumbnailURL = bexURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(bex.thumbnail)
        cell.file.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: thumbnailURL)!)    
        //fetch enable
        if bex.enable == false {
            cell.enable.setOn(false, animated: false)
        }
        else    {
            cell.enable.setOn(true, animated: false)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

below is screenshot of problem.

[table is loaded first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ez2W.png)
[after edit scene, unwind to table view. the edited cell is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw3OI.png)

please help suggest.

Comment: According to your code, you have a reference to your `tableView` in your Edit View Controller?

Comment: @noir_eagle , i do quite not understand your question.  Do i have to refer tableView in Edit View Controller and how to do it.
All i do now i Edit View Controller is passing data back to  tableView via   func "prepareForSegue".    

There is one more strange behaviour,    if i edit several cell continuously, sometimes the previous cell that used to be blank,   displays correctly.

i also have tried debugging,  and see that every data is passed to   cellForRowAtIndexPath  correctly.

Comment: `@IBAction func unwindToTableView(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)` is in your Edit View Controller, right? And you're using `tableView` instance, where and how you initialized it?

Comment: @AeyKungTaemin Can you the share the `prepareForSegue` method?

Comment: @noir_eagle,   No.  unwindToTableView is defined in TableViewController.

@ Viktor Simkó ,    here is prepareForSegue   
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if saveButton === sender {
            let name = nameTextField.text
            let file = fileName
            let enable = enableFlag
            bex = Bex(name: name, file: file, enable: enable)
        }

Answer (score 0):

I can now solve the issue.
I noticed that, sometimes a button or photo appears in the cell but its position is overlap with the cell's frame.

So I think it could be layout issue.
Then I tried to install all my objects and their position in Cell  in all size class related to iphone portrait.
And now problem solves.

previously, i worked on size class  "compact width, any height" only.

I think it is Xcode bug  that after unwinding to table view, Xcode layouts the cell with other size class, not the same size class when table is firstly loaded. The problem not happens only in simulator, but in device as well.
Before updating Xcode to latest version, I've never found this problem before.

Update-  May 10 2016,
I still think it is weird that Final Value Size Class does not overwrite Base Value size class.  And it is not normal to install objects and constraints to every size class.
So i tried uninstalled objects and constraints from all size class except Compact width regular height.  And The problem comes back.

Then I tried  disable size class from storyboard, keeps only iphone layout when asked in popup, and then re-enable it again.
Now The problem is gone.
It must a bug somewhere in Xcode after updating that affects to both simulator and deployed device.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this issue. I have the problem with Xcode 7 on the Simulator, but on the iPhone 4 all is good. I suggest that you mark your answer as accepted to show that there is a solution to the problem.